# Can java datetimeformatter handle custom text in date format

Tags: java, time, datetimeformatter

I store in a database:

- a week as `yyyyWww`, that is `2023W10` is 10<sup>th</sup> week of 2023
- a month as `2023M10` meaning October 2023

I can use `yyyy'W'ww` and `yyyy'M'MM` formats in `SimpleDateFormat`.

`DateTimeFormatter` gives `DateTimeParseException` in these cases.  Seems `DateTimeFormatter` will only accept a complete date (`year+month+day`) with limited text (dash, slash, period)

What am I missing here?

I have tried `yyyy'W'ww` and `yyyy'M'MM` formats in `dateTimeFormatter`, both give parseexceptions.

Comment: The Java 8+ `java.date` package's `DateTime...` classes expect date AND time. Have you tried calling `LocalDate.parse`?

Comment: Use regex replacement to add day 1 and massage the rest of the string into a format that can be parsed, e.g. [ISO_WEEK_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE)?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question properly. But both the format in question worked for me using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`, then `formatter.parse()` in openjdk 11.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No, no need for a date. Just use the appropriate class for each data type. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260836/642706).

Comment: *Seems `DateTimeFormatter` will only accept a complete date (year+month+day) with limited text (dash, slash, period)* In at least 2 respects not generally true. What made you think it was?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unlike others I downvoted. Because you have neither told us your expected result nor spelled out how you managed to get `DateTimeParseException` ([mre]) and what it looked like (exception message, stack trace). All of this is expected from a question like yours.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

In your specific cases, you could easily use string manipulation rather than `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek.parse( "2023W31".replace ( "W" , "-W" ) )
```

… and:

```
java.time.YearMonth.parse( "2023M07".replace( "M" , "-" ) )
```

Even better: Change your data to use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

- <s>2023W31</s> ➡️ 2023-W31
- <s>2023M07</s> ➡️ 2023-07

## Details

> What am I missing here?

You are missing the appropriate class.

### `YearWeek`

For your first case, a week of the year, use the [`org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class from the library [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/). This library adds functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8+, defined in JSR 310.

The `YearWeek` class uses standard  [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when parsing/generating text. So you need not specify a formatting pattern.

Your input text complies with the abbreviated style of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, but not the preferred expanded style. To comply with the expanded style, insert a hyphen, `input.replace( "W" , "-W" )`.

```java
String input = "2023W31".replace ( "W" , "-W" );
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.parse ( input );
System.out.println ( "yearWeek = " + yearWeek );
```

> yearWeek = 2023-W31

#### Define “week”

Use this `YearWeek` class only if your definition of “week” agrees with the ISO 8601 standard definition:

- Either 52 or 53 complete 7-day weeks per year.
- Week starts on Monday.
- Week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the calendar year.

### `YearMonth`

For your second case, use the [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class built into Java 8+.

The standard ISO 8601 format for a year and month is YYYY-MM. I recommend you use this standard format in your stored values in the database.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse( "2023-07" ) ;
```

If you insist on using your custom format, you might be able to define a `DateTimeFormatter` to specify your particular formatting pattern. But I would just replace the `M` with a hyphen.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse( "2023M07".replace( "M" , "-" ) ) ;
```

> yearMonth = 2023-07

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to apply defaults along with your pattern.

A simple approach would be to declare all known formats ahead of time and loop through them. If you want to eliminate the looping, you could check if the string contains a "W" and call the week parser, or an "M" and call the month parser.

Please note that `YYYY` (upper-case) denotes a week-based year, vs `yyyy` (lower-case) an era (normal 365 day year).

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

class DateParsing {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter
        PARSE_WEEK = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("YYYY'W'ww")
            .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue())
            .toFormatter(),
        PARSE_MONTH = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyy'M'MM")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
            .toFormatter();

    private static final DateTimeFormatter[] PATTERNS = { PARSE_WEEK, PARSE_MONTH };
    
    public static LocalDate parseDate(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (DateTimeFormatter pattern : PATTERNS) {
            try {
                return LocalDate.parse(input, pattern);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                // System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unknown format: %s", input));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String[] timestamps = {
            "2023W10", // 10th week of 2023
            "2023M10"  // October 1, 2023
        };
        for (String timestamp : timestamps) {
            System.out.printf(">>> %s => %s%n", timestamp, parseDate(timestamp));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
>>> 2023W10 => 2023-03-05
>>> 2023M10 => 2023-10-01
```

### Update

If you want to remove the loop and exception handling, you could check to see if the input string contains an "M" or "W" as explained above.

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

class DateParsing {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter
        PARSE_WEEK = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("YYYY'W'ww")
            .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue())
            .toFormatter(),
        PARSE_MONTH = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyy'M'MM")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
            .toFormatter();

    public static LocalDate parseDate(String input) throws DateTimeParseException, IllegalArgumentException {
        if (input.contains("M")) {
            return LocalDate.parse(input, PARSE_MONTH);
        }
        if (input.contains("W")) {
            return LocalDate.parse(input, PARSE_WEEK);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unknown format: %s", input));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DateTimeParseException, IllegalArgumentException {
        String[] timestamps = {
            "2023W10", // 10th week of 2023
            "2023M10"  // October 1, 2023
        };
        for (String timestamp : timestamps) {
            System.out.printf(">>> %s => %s%n", timestamp, parseDate(timestamp));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot in good conscience upvote code with `catch (Exception e)` in it.  Why not just catch DateTimeParseException?  Also, `throws IllegalArgumentException` is essentially meaningless, since all methods are automatically capable of throwing unchecked exceptions.

Comment: @VGR my bad, I meant `DateTimeParseException`. I originally wrote each try-catch out and defaulted to `Exeception`, before I introduced the loop. I only made it unchecked for demonstration purposes. I added a safer version at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks.  The `throws` clauses are still unnecessary, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all the input. I did not know about the ISO date formats, in future I will use them. My requirement is to average values such as prices from day to week and month. So far as I can tell, the deficiencies in date/calendar will not affect the values I produce.  When they are deprecated, I will bite the bullet and re-code.